# Change class of div on scroll for a certain range only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use the scroll function to change the class of an element. The following code works fine:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
     $('.row-1').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
 });
```

But what if you want to change the class only for a range between >1 and <1000?
Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional expression (i.e. `$(this).scrollTop() > 1`) can be expanded to have two conditions. The value from [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) can be stored in a variable (using [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), unless [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility) is an issue- then use [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)) so as to reduce queries on the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). Then use the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Binary_logical_operators) operator (i.e. `&&`) to combine the conditions.

```
 let scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
 $('.row-1').toggleClass('scrolled', scrollTop > 1 && scrollTop < 1000);
```

See this demonstrated below

```js
$(() => { //wait until DOM is ready
  const scrollVal = $('#scrollVal');
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    const scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.row-1').toggleClass('scrolled', scrollTop > 1 && scrollTop < 1000);
    scrollVal.text(scrollTop+'px');
  });

  //add some div elements for demonstration purposes
  new Array(10).fill().forEach((element, index) => $('<div>').addClass('row-' + (index % 2)).text('row' + (index % 2)).appendTo(document.body));
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 80px;
}

.scrolled {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}

#scrollValContainer {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollValContainer">
Scroll: <span id="scrollVal">0px</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    const rangeTrue = $(this).scrollTop() > 1 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1000;
    $('.row-1').toggleClass('scrolled', rangeTrue);
});
```

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) but in the context of the scroll callback, that value shouldn't change so [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) would suffice as well.